# SQL between two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, select

I have an issue between two tables in sql

Table 1

| name_id | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SPEC-A | 100 | 110 | 120 |
| SPEC-B | 200 | 120 | 130 |

Table 2

| name | name_id | cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M.John | SPEC-B | 2 |
| J.Smith | SPEC-A | 3 |

So I would like to connect two tables where I would like to select persons name_id and his category in table 2 with rows and columns in table 1

```
select * 
from table 1
inner join table 2 on table1.name_id = table2.name_id
```

But I can't connect table2.cat with each columns in table 1
for example table2.cat = 2  with table1.2 automaticly

Comment: Can you describe a little better what you are trying to get? Result examples.

Comment: what is the header in table 1? column names? if yes how 2 exists twice?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have using a join?

Comment: If the names of the tables are `table1` and `table2`, then you need `select table2.cat, table1.* from table2 inner join table1 on table2.name_id = table1.name_id`.

Comment: I would like to see next:

| M.John  | SPEC-B  |  2 |  120  |
|

Answer (score 0):

To associate a value to a column, you will need a `CASE WHEN` like this:

```sql
    SELECT
    * 
    , CASE
        WHEN table2.cat = 1 THEN table1.[1]
        WHEN table2.cat = 2 THEN table1.[2]
        WHEN table2.cat = 3 THEN table1.[3]
        END AS price
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name_id = table2.name_id
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**