# SQL between two tables where we tacking good result

Tags: sql, mysql

I have an issue between two tables in sql

Table 1

| name_id | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SPEC-A | 100 | 110 | 120 |
| SPEC-B | 200 | 220 | 230 |

Table 2

| name | name_id | cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M.John | SPEC-B | 2 |
| J.Smith | SPEC-A | 3 |

So I would like to connect two tables where I would like to select persons name_id and his category in table 2 with rows and columns in table 1

```
select * 
from table 1
inner join table 2 on table1.name_id = table2.name_id
```

But I can't connect table2.cat with each columns in table 1
for example table2.cat = 2  with table1.2 automaticaly.

I would like to see next:

| name | name_id | cat | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M.John | SPEC-B | 2 | 220 |
| J.Smith | SPEC-A | 3 | 120 |

I would like to see next:

| name | name_id | cat | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M.John | SPEC-B | 2 | 220 |
| J.Smith | SPEC-A | 3 | 120 |

Comment: Somewhat better, but why didn't you edit your previous question instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77947132/sql-between-two-tables

Comment: BTW, how is this related to php? I see no php code above, and I doubt you expect a php answer.

Comment: Yes I am agree with you, in this issue i need only sql

Comment: Your problem is the inappropriate data model. In one table you make categories 1, 2 and 3 part of the table structure and in the other they are mere data. You should change the first table to `table1(name_id, cat, price)`. Thus the data model would be consistent and you could just join directly without any tricks.

Answer (score 2):

In a consistently designed database table1 would look like this: `table1 (name_id, cat, price)`.

You say, though, that you are forced to work with the inappropriately designed table.

My suggestion: Tell them they should change their data model. If they are intelligent people they will probably do so.

If they don't, create a view that represents the missing table:

```
create view view1 (name_id, cat, price) as
  select name_id, 1 as cat, `1` as price
  union all
  select name_id, 2 as cat, `2` as price
  union all
  select name_id, 3 as cat, `3` as price
;
```

The column names 1, 2 and 3 are a horror of course and can cause problems. Above `CREATE VIEW` statement uses syntax that is valid only in MySQL. Standard SQL does not use backticks for names. In standard SQL you'd use double quotes (`"`) instead. So depending on what mode MySQL is run in, one or the other form will be invalid. With such names the database administrator must make sure to decide for one mode and rigidly stick to it.

The query will become a simple:

```
select *
from view1 t1
join table2 t2 using(name_id, cat)
```

If you are not allowed to create the view and they don't do it for you either, then use an ad-hoc view:

```
with view1 as ( <see above> )
  select *
  from view1 t1
  join table2 t2 using(name_id, cat)
```

Answer (score 1):

The query will be :

```
WITH T AS
(    
SELECT T2.name, T2.name_id, T2.cat,
        CASE T2.cat WHEN 1 THEN T1."1"
                    WHEN 2 THEN T1."2"
                    WHEN 3 THEN T1."3"
        END AS price
FROM    "Table 1" AS T1
           JOIN "Table 2" AS T2
              ON T1.name_id = T2.name_id 
)
SELECT *
FROM   T
WHERE  price IS NOT NULL;
```

But your data structure does not respects the state of art in data modeling.... SO the performances will be catastrophic....

Table 1 will gain to be split into 2 tables :

```
CREATE "Table 1" 
(name_id VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE "Table 1.1" 
(name_id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL REFERENCES "Table 1" (name_id), 
 cat INT NOT NULL, 
 price DECIMAL(16,2) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (name_id, cat );
```

Then you can have a view that presents the old version of "Table 1"... (with some PIVOT operator or at least a CASE statement).

Comment: I am agree with you but client give me this tables so maybe I must change table1 from row to collumn

Comment: No change table 1 for two tables... One with only name_id and the other with name_id, cat, price

Comment: `T1."1"` is not how you refer to a column named 1 in mysql

Comment: @ysth: You do when running sql_mode = 'ANSI', which is not a bad idea generally.

Comment: names in SQL (the real term is "SQL identifier") for tables, columns, constraints... Must be in the form : 1) max 128 chars, 2) beginning by a letter or the underscore _ 3) having only A to Z +  0 to 9 + _ chars 4) not being a SQL keyword (there are almost 300 keywords in SQL)

Comment: @SQLpro: ysth is refering to the quotes. While it is double quotes in standard SQL, it is backticks in MySQL's default mode. And the restrictions you name apply to some particular DBMS, not SQL in general. In most DBMS you can use umlauts (äöü) in identifiers, too, for instance.

Comment: If an SQL identifier deviates from the naming rule, then it is necessary to surround it with double quotes. Otherwise, this may lead to an interpretation or syntax error. Furthermore, if you use characters outside of 7-bit ASCII (for example accented letters) there is a risk that certain applications will throw an exception. Don't forget that **a RDBMS is not there to do cosmetics...** This role must be assigned to the application layer only... Also the introduction of a character such as "ü" is bad practice which can be blocking...

Answer (score 1):

It's so much easier to talk about your problem if you use realistic column names.  I'm using table1 etc and col2 etc.

```
select table2.name, table2.name_id,
    elt(table2.cat, table1.col1, table1.col2, table1.col3) price
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.name_id = table2.name_id
```